# Zend3 Model subtype

Tags: php, zend-framework3

Learning Zend3 framework. Working on a sample Zend3 project where I have to create a Model sub-type.

I have following Book.php model:

```
<?php

namespace Products\Model;

class Book
{
    public $id;
    public $author;
    public $title;
    public $isbn;



    public function exchangeArray(array $data)
    {
        $this->id     = !empty($data['id']) ? $data['id'] : null;
        $this->author = !empty($data['author']) ? $data['author'] : null;
        $this->title  = !empty($data['title']) ? $data['title'] : null;
        $this->isbn  = !empty($data['isbn']) ? $data['isbn'] : null;
    }

    public function getArrayCopy()
    {
        return [
            'id'     => $this->id,
            'author' => $this->author,
            'title'  => $this->title,
            'isbn'  => $this->isbn,

        ];
    } 

}
```

Now I have to create:

A sub-type of "Book" which is called "Thriller", inherits from "Book" and has an additional property called "excitement_factor"

while:

it properly reflect this relationship in the database as well as your models and, I should:

Ensure database integrity also, finally:

implement adequate table model functions for retrieving, saving and deleting "thriller"s, use ORM-style for all queries

How can I do this?

Should make Thriller extend Book class with new field? How do I do this in Zend3? What about the underlying table? Will Zend create new table for Thriller? Which files I have to adjust?

With ORM Style methods it is meant fetchAll(), fetchOneBy() etc ?

Thanks,

**Update 1:**

My Book table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE book (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, author varchar(100) NOT NULL, title varchar(100) NOT NULL, isbn varchar(100) NOT NULL, type ENUM("Thriller") NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id))
```

Created second table Thriller:

```
CREATE TABLE thriller
(
    id INT NOT NULL,
    book INT NOT NULL,
    excitement_factor VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(book) REFERENCES book(id)
)
```

Both have TableGateways.

Models are below:

```
cat Book.php 
<?php

namespace Products\Model;

class Book
{
    public $id;
    public $author;
    public $title;
    public $isbn;

    private $inputFilter;

    public function exchangeArray(array $data)
    {
        $this->id     = !empty($data['id']) ? $data['id'] : null;
        $this->author = !empty($data['author']) ? $data['author'] : null;
        $this->title  = !empty($data['title']) ? $data['title'] : null;
        $this->isbn  = !empty($data['isbn']) ? $data['isbn'] : null;
    }

    public function getArrayCopy()
    {
        return [
            'id'     => $this->id,
            'author' => $this->author,
            'title'  => $this->title,
            'isbn'  => $this->isbn,

        ];
    } 

}
cat BookTable.php 
<?php

namespace Products\Model;

use RuntimeException;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGatewayInterface;

class BookTable
{
    private $tableGateway;

    public function __construct(TableGatewayInterface $tableGateway)
    {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }

    public function fetchAll()
    {
        return $this->tableGateway->select();
    }

    public function getBook($id)
    {
        $id = (int) $id;
        $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(['id' => $id]);
        $row = $rowset->current();
        if (! $row) {
            throw new RuntimeException(sprintf(
                'Could not find row with identifier %d',
                $id
            ));
        }

        return $row;
    }

    public function saveBook(Book $book)
    {
        $data = [
            'author' => $book->author,
            'title'  => $book->title,
            'isbn'  => $book->isbn,

        ];

        $id = (int) $book->id;

        if ($id === 0) {
            $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
            return;
        }

        if (! $this->getBook($id)) {
            throw new RuntimeException(sprintf(
                'Cannot update book with identifier %d; does not exist',
                $id
            ));
        }

        $this->tableGateway->update($data, ['id' => $id]);
    }

    public function deleteBook($id)
    {
        $this->tableGateway->delete(['id' => (int) $id]);
    }
}

cat Thriller.php 
<?php

namespace Products\Model;

class Thriller
{
    public $id;
    public $book;
    public $excitement_factor;

    private $inputFilter;

    public function exchangeArray(array $data)
    {
        $this->tid     = !empty($data['id']) ? $data['id'] : null;
        $this->book = !empty($data['book']) ? $data['book'] : null;
        $this->excitement_factor = !empty($data['excitement_factor']) ? $data['excitement_factor'] : null;
    }

    public function getArrayCopy()
    {
        return [
            'id'     => $this->id,
            'book' => $this->book,
            'excitement_factor' => $this->excitement_factor,

        ];
    } 

}

cat ThrillerTable.php 
<?php

namespace Products\Model;

use RuntimeException;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGatewayInterface;

class ThrillerTable
{
    private $tableGateway;

    public function __construct(TableGatewayInterface $tableGateway)
    {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }

    public function fetchAll()
    {
        return $this->tableGateway->select();
    }

    public function getThriller($id)
    {
        $id = (int) $id;
        $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(['id' => $id]);
        $row = $rowset->current();
        if (! $row) {
            throw new RuntimeException(sprintf(
                'Could not find row with identifier %d',
                $id
            ));
        }

        return $row;
    }

    public function saveThriller(Thriller $thriller)
    {
        $data = [
            'book' => $thriller->book,
            'excitement_factor'  => $thriller->excitement_factor,


        ];

        $id = (int) $thriller->id;

        if ($id === 0) {
            $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
            return;
        }

        if (! $this->getThriller($id)) {
            throw new RuntimeException(sprintf(
                'Cannot update thriller with identifier %d; does not exist',
                $id
            ));
        }

        $this->tableGateway->update($data, ['id' => $id]);
    }

    public function deleteThriller($id)
    {
        $this->tableGateway->delete(['id' => (int) $id]);
    }
}
```

In my controller to add Book, I simply do:

```
public function addBookAction()
    {
        $form = new BookForm();
        $form->get('submit')->setValue('Add');

        $request = $this->getRequest();

        if (! $request->isPost()) {
            return ['form' => $form];
        }

        $bookForm = new BookForm();
        $form->setInputFilter($bookForm->getInputFilter());
        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        if (! $form->isValid()) {
            return ['form' => $form];
        }

        $bookModel = new Book();

        $bookModel->exchangeArray($form->getData());


        $this->book->saveBook($bookModel);
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('product');
    }
```

How do I add now Thriller?

```
public function addThrillerAction()
{
    // ???
}
```

Comment: zf has a tutorial about creating modul which has CRUD operations. here you are documentation link. https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/

Comment: Thanks. I know how to create Modules and use TableGateway to bind Model to Database. However I don't understand how should I solve creation of Subtypes? Do you know any resources/sample app which uses Subtypes?

Comment: Same as pure php. just extends them. What's making you that much think about it?

Comment: Hmmm ..... Please see Update 1: .... I dont know how to extend my model, in my concrete example how to add new Thriller. I would imagine it should get book id and add it in Thriller table along with excitement factor ... Maybe my approach is wrong and this has to be done differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does "Thriller" has to be a book object? Maybe it can be a "genre" of book object. In this approach book object has a property as "genres" and of course "addGenre/removeGenre/hasGenre/getGenres" methods. I mean each book can have more than one genre. Also you can keep all genres in a table, fetch them and populate form. By the way you can run queries on them. A pivot table would be enough to keep books and genres relationships.

Comment: Thanks. Yes Thriller should be a book object. I thought in Zend3 there is a easy way to do it. But i guess i will have to run queries (select on Book table and insert in Thriller) using Zend_Db_Table. Is Zend_Db_Table still good to use with Zend3? Or it is deprecated and there are new ways to do queries?

Comment: its Zend\Db now and it's still good. also you can use some kind orm too like doctrine. its up to you.